# I am trying to connect to an online redis server from heroku but my connection is getting refused

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, ioredis

I am using the Redis package for Node.js (`ioredis`),  I have a redis cluster hosted on ScaleGrid that I am trying to connect to from heroku but i keep getting the error `[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14) Redis Error: { ReplyError: NOAUTH Authentication required.`. This is my code

```
//This is what my redis uri provided by ScaleGrid uri looks like, this is not exact string though
REDIS_URI=SG-Stack-12345.servers.mongodirector.com:6379

import session from 'express-session';
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

const redisClient = process.env.REDIS_URI;

const redis = new Redis(redisClient);
const redisStore = connectRedis(session);

redis.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Redis Error:', err);
});

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  name: '_redisSession',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  store: new redisStore({ client: redis, ttl: 86400 }),
}));
```

Please how do i solve this issue? and also why do i still get this `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

**P.S.** Redis works perfectly on my localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized all i needed was to send the password for authentication immediately after the redis client connects`(client.auth(password)`. 
I had to settle for `redislabs enterprise` for my redis hosting and also had to change from `ioredis` package to `redis` package because of some strange errors. This is the code below

**redis.js**

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const {
  PASSWORD: password,
  REDIS_HOST: host, // On localhost, set to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'
  REDIS_PORT: port, // On localhost,  set to 6379
} = process.env;

// connect to Redis host with port and host set as environment variables
const client = createClient(port, host, { no_ready_check: true });

// If password is in environment variable, send password to the host for authentication
if (password) {
  client.auth(password, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}

client.on('connect', () => console.log('connected to Redis'));

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Redis Error:', err);
});

export default client;
```

This is optional, it only shows how the connected redis client is utilized in the index file.

**index.js**

```
import session from 'express-session';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import client from './redis'

const redisStore = connectRedis(session);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'IwontTell',
  name: '_stackOverflow',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  store: new redisStore({ client, ttl: 86400 }),
}));
```

This works perfecly both on localhost and online. Hope this helps someone